# Not able to include jndi.jar file in android project build path

Tags: android

I need to do LDAP authentication of my users in Android application , for the same I am using JNDI lookup method and need to include JNDI.jar in my build path , but android is not letting me do so and throwing the following error

> [2011-02-17 15:08:33 - DHCAndroid]: Dx trouble processing
>   "javax/naming/AuthenticationException.class":
>
> Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) when
>   not building a core library.
>
> This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file in
>   your application's project, when using an IDE (such as Eclipse). If
>   you are sure you're not intentionally defining a core class, then this
>   is the most likely explanation of what's going on.
>
> However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
>   namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example, from a
>   non-Android virtual machine project. This will most assuredly not
>   work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the compatibility of your app with
>   future versions of the platform. It is also often of questionable
>   legality.
>
> If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
>   appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine distribution,
>   as opposed to compiling an application -- then use the
>   "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
>
> If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact building an
>   application, then be forewarned that your application will still fail
>   to build or run, at some point. Please be prepared for angry customers
>   who find, for example, that your application ceases to function once
>   they upgrade their operating system. You will be to blame for this
>   problem.
>
> If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a core
>   package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to repackage
>   that code. That is, move the classes in question into your own package
>   namespace. This means that they will never be in conflict with core
>   system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help you in this endeavor.
>   If you find that you cannot do this, then that is an indication that
>   the path you are on will ultimately lead to pain, suffering, grief,
>   and lamentation.
>
> [2011-02-17 15:08:33 - DHCAndroid]: Dx1 error; aborting [2011-02-17
>   15:08:33 - DHCAndroid] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

As soon as i remove the jar the error disappears, removing the jar is not an option , please help with the way to do it

Regards,
Smriti Garg

Answer (score 0):

Find another LDAP library, then, one that is not in the `javax` namespace. What you want to do with this JAR is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Add the dex parameter --core-library to the [ANDROID_SDK]\platform-tools\dx.bat.

Change line ~59 of dx.bat: 'set params=' to `'set params=--core-library'`

This enables the Android build process to allow including javax pacakges.

Answer (score 0):

Like the error message says:

> move the classes in question into your own package namespace.
>   [...] JarJar is a tool that may help you in this endeavor.

Repackage the JNDI code into your own namespace, by using JarJar. Then rely on your new jar instead.